# How to remove section of audio from video file?

Tags: audio, avidemux

I have a short video clip with audio. Towards the end is a voiceover that I want to remove. I'm trying to use avidemux to edit this, but I don't see any way to remove just a portion of the audio. Everything is all on a single stream.

The closest I've found is to make a selection for the part of the video I want to keep the audio for, do Audio->Save Audio, then remove all of the existing tracks and re-save the video file. Unfortunately, this doesn't work; 'Save Audio' does give me a file, but the final video has no sound at all.

The audio is ogg vorbis, and the avidemux site warns "using that method will save the raw audio track. If it is AAC or Vorbis, you will end up with an unplayable file as they need a container to be playable." I'm assuming that adding the container will fix this, but I have absolutely no idea how to do that either.

Is there an easy way to solve this?

Comment: Any good video editor should support this.  Sounds like you need something more powerful than `avidemux`

Comment: VirtualDub has always been good for me and it does allow editing of chunks of audio like you talk about. Might want to try it?

Comment: I gave up on VirtualDub since it kept giving me codec issues. It doesn't seem to like .mkv files, even after getting the plugin for them.